# Dataframe Is No Longer Accessible

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, nonetype

I am trying to make my code look better and create functions that do all the work from running just one line but it is not working as intended. I am currently pulling data from a pdf that is in a table into a pandas dataframe. From there I have 4 functions, all calling each other and finally returning the updated dataframe. I can see that it is full updated when I print it in the last method. However I am unable to access and use that updated dataframe, even after I return it.

My code is as follows

```
def data_cleaner(dataFrame):
    #removing random rows
    removed = dataFrame.drop(columns=['Unnamed: 1','Unnamed: 2','Unnamed: 4','Unnamed: 5','Unnamed: 7','Unnamed: 9','Unnamed: 11','Unnamed: 13','Unnamed: 15','Unnamed: 17','Unnamed: 19'])
    #call next method
    col_combiner(removed)

def col_combiner(dataFrame):
    
    #Grabbing first and second row of table to combine
    first_row = dataFrame.iloc[0]
    second_row = dataFrame.iloc[1]
    #List to combine columns
    newColNames = []
    #Run through each row and combine them into one name
    for i,j in zip(first_row,second_row):
        #Check to see if they are not strings, if they are not convert it
        if not isinstance(i,str):
            i = str(i)
        if not isinstance(j,str):
            j = str(j)
        newString = ''
        #Check for double NAN case and change it to Expenses
        if i == 'nan' and j == 'nan':
            i = 'Expenses'
            newString = newString + i
        #Check for leading NAN and remove it
        elif i == 'nan':
            newString = newString + j
        else:            
            newString = newString + i + ' ' + j
            
    
        newColNames.append(newString)
    
    #Now update the dataframes column names
    dataFrame.columns = newColNames
    
    #Remove the name rows since they are now the column names
    dataFrame = dataFrame.iloc[2:,:]
    
    #Going to clean the values in the DF
    clean_numbers(dataFrame)


def clean_numbers(dataFrame):
    #Fill NAN values with 0
    noNan = dataFrame.fillna(0)
    
    #Pull each column, clean the values, then put it back
    for i in range(noNan.shape[1]):
        colList = noNan.iloc[:,i].tolist()
        #calling to clean the column so that it is all ints
        col_checker(colList)
        noNan.iloc[:,i] = colList
    
    
    return noNan

def col_checker(col):
    #Going through, checking and cleaning
    for i in range(len(col)):
        #print(type(colList[i]))
        if isinstance(col[i],str):
            col[i] = col[i].replace(',','')
            if col[i].isdigit():
                #print('not here')
                col[i] = int(col[i]) 
            #If it is not a number then make it 0
            else:
                col[i] = 0
```

Then when I run this:

```
doesThisWork = data_cleaner(cleaner)
type(doesThisWork)
```

I get NoneType. I might be doing this the long way as I am new to this, so any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: Your `data_cleaner` function doesn't have a `return` statement, therefore it returns `None`. You need to add `return something` to it.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @pgaluzio I see! I think where my understanding failed me is the way python stores memory. I always thought that when I am working on a Dataframe that it is a global variable so that if I put it through a method it updates the df without needing to return something new. Thank you for your help!

Comment: There are two things happening here: 1st, is your function changing the input parameter `cleaner` (which you can do because dataframes are [mutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types)); 2nd, is you assigning the function return value to your `doesThisWork ` variable. After your function call, `cleaner` may be changed **and** `doesThisWork` may have been assigned a value returned by your function. Be aware that this is usually poor design, you should try to have your functions doing only one thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting `NoneType` is because your function does not have a `return` statement, meaning that when finishing executing it will automatically returns `None`. And it is the return value of a function that is assigned to a variable `var` in a statement like this:

```py
var = fun(x)
```

Now, a different thing entirely is whether or not your dataframe `cleaner` will be changed by the function `data_cleaner`, which can happen because dataframes are [mutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types) objects in Python.

In other words, your function can read your dataframe and change it, so after the function call `cleaner` is different than before. At the same time, your function can return a value (which it doesn't) and this value will be assigned to `doesThisWork`.

Usually, you should prefer that your function does [only one thing](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/402979/what-does-it-mean-for-a-method-or-a-function-to-do-one-thing#402981), so expect that the function changes its argument **and** return a value is usually bad practice.